# Query Mongoose Schema. nested array of comments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have venues, which each have a comments section. Each comment is a Mongoose Comment schema. Each comment has a creator property, which is a User schema. I'm trying to find all comments a specific user has posted. How can I do this?

```
var VenueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  comments: [{
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Comment',
    default: []
  }]
},
{minimize: false});

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  creator: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
}, {minimize: false});


var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  token: String,
  venues: [{ //in case we want users to save their favorite venues
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Venue'
  }]
});
```

I have tried

```
Venue.find({
    "comments.creator":  "55f1fa1263877ed0067b78c0"
  }, function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    res.send(docs);
  })
```

but it returns an empty array. The "55f1fa1263877ed0067b78c0" is a sample creator _id. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you cannot search `creater` by its id inside `Venue` collection becouse it collects only `Comment` ID. So in order to search `creater` by its id you need to change like below:

```
var VenueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  comments: [CommentSchema]
},
{minimize: false});

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  creator: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
}, {minimize: false});


var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  token: String,
  venues: [{ //in case we want users to save their favorite venues
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Venue'
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As venueSchema is storing only ref to comments (which would be comments _id), you will not be able to query comment using venue model. Either you have embed comment document into comments array of venue schema.

Or

Just query the comment collection using comment model as below

```
Comment.find({
    "creator":  "55f1fa1263877ed0067b78c0"
  }, function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    res.send(docs);
  })
```